# Create a non repeat random number generator

Tags: javascript

I am creating a random number generator. I get the numbers but they repeat sometimes. Here is my code

```
var myRandom

function randomNumGen(max, min) {
var randomNum = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    randomNum[i] = Math.random() * (max - min +1) + min ;
    randomNum[i] = Math.round(randomNum[i]);
}
return randomNum;
}
myRandom = randomNumGen(1, 53);
console.log(" Here are your numbers." + myRandom);
```

What am i missing in order to make the numbers not repeat?

Comment: You need to store the numbers that are already 'taken' (maybe in an array). Then when you're generating the random numbers, simple check the array or taken numbers. If it finds one, regenerate.

Comment: If it's small, generate an array with the possible values. Shuffle and pop. Not so good if a giant range, if so, then stir a map/set of used numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see of achieving this would be to check every random number generated against the numbers already in the array. If there is a number which repeats you would generate another random number and check again and so-on until you came upon a unique number.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I'm pretty new to this. Thanks

Comment: Better to store the numbers in a set or mail so you don't have to iterate or search a "taken" array.

Comment: Map. Autocomplete makes everything butter.

Comment: This will perform badly on a large range, with few numbers left available, as you may have to generate many random numbers before finding an unused one.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
function range(start, stop) {
  var array = [];

  for (var i = start; i <= stop; i += 1) {
     array.push(i);
  }

  return array; 
}

var nums = range(1, 53).sort(function () { 
   return (Math.random() < 0.5) ? 1 : -1; 
}).slice(0, 6);
```

The code snippet above generates a sequence of numbers within a certain range, shuffles them and then extracts the first n numbers. This method guarantees that the numbers extracted are unique because of the way they are generated. It may not be an optimal solution if the range is huge, but for small intervals it will do just fine.

Comment: You could also randomize the array upfront, perhaps using something like the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), and simply read the resulting array sequentially. Conceptually similar to drawing from a shuffled deck of playing cards.

Comment: Code–only answers aren't great. You should explain why your solution fixes the OP's issue.

Comment: @RobG Added an explanation. I thought the solution was simple enough to be self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

The first way to avoid duplicates is to store all found numbers as you generate new ones and discard any numbers that have already been generated. You can search in an array for a number with [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). Just add this at the end of the for loop:

```
if(randomNum.indexOf(randomNum[i]) < i) --i;
```

It will basically run the loop again for the same array cell if that number was already in the array. There's one danger with this method: it makes in infinite loop if you pass in min and max values that don't have more than 6 possible results.

The other way to do this is to generate all possible numbers first and then pick some out of the list, removing them afterward. Honestly, this solution is more appropriate when you have a small range of values and many numbers to pick, while you have a very small amount of vales to pick.

PS, don't use `math.round` as it gives unequal chances for the edge cases. For example, a random number between 0 and 2 will be rounded to 0 for any random value from 0 to <0.5 but rounded to 1 for any value from 0.5 to <1.5 (For more even distribution, use `math.floor` and add 1 to the result - but you already got that right.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to build a 'taken numbers array' and check that array for any matches with the random number generated. If it doesn't exist, go ahead and add it.

```
var takenNumbers = [];
$('#btnGo').on('click', function () {
    var theRandomNumbersArray = randomNumGen(50, 0);
});

function randomNumGen(max, min) {
    var counter = 0;
    var returnArray = [];
    while (counter < 6) {
        var randomNumber = Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min;
        var randomNumberRounded = Math.round(randomNumber);

        if (takenNumbers.indexOf(randomNumberRounded.toString()) == -1) {
            takenNumbers.push(randomNumberRounded);
            returnArray.push(randomNumberRounded);
            counter += 1;
        }
    }
    return returnArray;
}
```

**NOTE:** One bug here that you'll need to account for. If using a `while` loop, it could spin off into an infinite loop if all the numbers are taken. You might want to also check to see the array has a length of the max number or something to that affect.